# Dynamic Forms Angular 2 - Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, angular2-forms

I am new in Angular 2. I am trying to expand dynamic forms according to `https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form`. I did input radios and work as I need. But now I am trying to do checkboxes, but there is a problem. I have a group of checkboxes and I get only boolean value, if some checkbox is checked. Bud I need values, which checkboxes is checked. There is my plunker: `https://plnkr.co/edit/EhtpprYdXIFmYJG7Lzxg`

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would be the solution for you.

templet.html

```
<form [formGroup] = "myForm" (ngSubmit) = "confirmFlights(myForm.value)">
  <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="flightList" let-flight let-i="index" >
     <input type="checkbox" [value]="flight.id" formControlName="flightid"
         (change)="flightids[i]=[$event.target.checked,$event.target.getAttribute('value')]" >
  </ng-template>
</form>
```

component.ts

flightids array will have another arrays like this 
[ [ true, 'id_1'], [ false, 'id_2'], [ true, 'id_3']...]
here true means user checked it, false means user checked then unchecked it.
The items that user have never checked will not be inserted to the array.

```
flightids = []; 
confirmFlights(value){  
    //console.log(this.flightids);

    let confirmList = [];
    this.flightids.forEach(id => {
      if(id[0]) // here, true means that user checked the item 
        confirmList.push(this.flightList.find(x => x.id === id[1]));
    });
    //console.log(confirmList);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Why it isn't working:***

because you are using **one formControl** key (question.key === 'skills') for **all 3 checkboxes**.

```
<span *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
   <p *ngFor="let opt of question.options">
      <input [formControlName]="question.key"
         [id]="opt.key" type="checkbox" [value]="opt.key">
           <label>{{opt.value}}</label></p>
</span>
```

***How to deal with it:***

You **should use formControl key for each input** (checkbox), to track model changes - this is how Angular forms works.

So, if you **split** your Checkbox.options to **separate** Checkbox, it would work:

in ***dynamic-form-question.component.html*** change Checkbox to:

```
<span *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
  <input [formControlName]="question.key"
    [id]="question.key" type="checkbox" [value]="question.value">
</span>
```

in ***question.service.ts*** change Checkbox to:

```
new CheckboxQuestion({
    key: 'fast',
    label: 'Fast',
    value: false,
    order: 5
}),
```

Here is changed Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/2XIfMU?p=preview

Comment: I think you've over complicated this. While the reason / cause is correct, there is already the mechanics in place to add a checkbox without needing `CheckboxQuestion`. The `TextboxQuestion` accepts a `type` (see the email one). Simply passing in a type of `checkbox` will change the Input type to be a checkbox. Suddenly you lose the need for the new class, the new HTML, the switch case. Re-usability!

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox or radio doesn't update automatically (at this point I'm not sure if this is caused by angular design or possibly due to [MDN: DOM input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)).

The usage of a template reference variable works but only for one FormControl within a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup).

More elegant solution: you can set a [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl)'s value (in a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)) directly from the change event:

```
(change)="formGroup.controls[element.name].setValue($event.target.checked)"
```

Since FormControl.[setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue)'s *emitEvent*, *emitModelToViewChange* and *emitViewToModelChange* default to `true`, it's seems not necessary to update other attributes manually.

Modified for angular's [dynamic form](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) ([working example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prymqa)):

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'" [formControlName]="question.key"
        [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type" (change)="form.controls[question.key].setValue($event.target.checked)">
```